# how to store key-value as well as value-key in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, key-value

I have this somewhat big data structure that stores pairs of data. The individual data is tiny and readily hashable, and there are something like a few hundred thousand data points in there.

At first, this was a simple dict that was accessed only by keys. Later on however, I discovered that I also needed to access it by value, that is, get the key for a certain value. Since this was done somewhat less often (~1/10) than access by key, I naïvely implemented it by simply iterating over all the dicts `items()`. Which proved a bit sluggish at a few hundred thousand calls per second. It is about 500 times slower.

So my next idea was to just use save the reverse dict, too. This seems to be a rather inelegant solution however, so I turn to you guys for help.

Do you know any data structure in Python that stores data pairs that can be accessed by either data point of the pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [bidict](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict/0.1.1).